# If jquery.html() doesn't work in xhtml because innerHTML is messy and not a good practice, why do jquery.prepend() etc work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wouldn't allowing users to input xhtml manually create the exact problem removing `innerHTML` was supposed to solve?

Comment: Cannot tell what is being asked here.. `innerHTML` is fine, jQuery is fine, `XHTML` is fine, what's the problem? Or are you implying that `innerHTML` only works for `HTML` and not `XHTML`? Then I will ask a counter question: wtf?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because pretend, etc. does not touch `innerHTML`.  With those, jQuery is converting your text to DOM nodes and adding them to the page using the `childNode` arrays and other features.

EDIT: Whoops, never mind, my mistake.  It does use innerHTML to parse the html.  The only difference is that the innerHTML of the target isn't directly modified because when you feed the selector function html, it creates a new node and doesn't directly modify the target's innerHTML.  Thanks, Esailija.

Comment: prepend,append,after,before use innerHTML to convert text into DOM nodes.. why would they reinvent the parser in javascript?

Comment: Interesting, so slightly screwy xhtml should come out fine when jquery handles it?